# Can you buy Wii U downloadable titles without a Wii U?

Tags: wii-u

With the Playstation Store I believe you can actually purchase PSN titles from your PC for the PSP (and possibly PS3? I forget). I've googled but I can't quite tell if there's such a service for the Wii U store.

There's a Wii U downloadable title I'd like, as it's on sale, but I don't have a Wii U yet. Is there some way I can purchase the game (even if I have to download it on the title, just "claiming" it would be super) without the console itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you can't, Nintendo ties the download with the console, not with the User ID.

Comment: Which also means if you sell the console, the buyer gets your games...

Comment: Ug really? Then it's just like the Wii for now...

Answer (score 2):

Update since the answer has changed. Unlike three years ago, you can now buy titles on Nintendo's website, and they will email you a download code. You can save this code and enter it in on a Wii U console at any time later to download the game. The same system applies to 3DS.

Nintendo Support [link](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12391) on giving games as gifts (though you can also just use the code yourself).

Answer (score 0):

There is also another option. If you create a Nintendo Network ID, (hereafter NNID), you can register a download with your NNID, and can download it whenever you want, as long as the game is still being distributed. You must have a NNID, and it must be connected to a Nintendo Account (I believe).